# VSCode multiline text selection off by one

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I am having a problem with text selection highlight in VSCode. It seems that the highlighting is a bit "off" when selecting multiple lines.

In the image above, there's no trailing white spaces but the highlight still covers as if there's one in each line. Also on the first line the actual selection starts from `'` but the highlight also covers the white space in front.

This problem doesn't happen if I use column mode for the selection. It also doesn't happen if the selection has no vertical overlap between lines.

My guess is that something's wrong with the highlight visualization when it tries to merge the highlight between two lines to have a rounded corner but I have no idea where to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the question? Please [edit] to clarify. If you weren't aware, Stack Overflow is a Q&A site; see the [tour] (and for tips, [ask]). If you actually want to file a bug report, you can do that [on the VSCode GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: It'd help to provide the text from the screenshot as text [so that we can verify the issue ourselves](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). It'd also help to add details: What version of VSCode are you running? What do you mean by "no vertical overlap between lines"? Show an example please.

Comment: Some of those trailing highlights are for the **newlines**. That's not specific to VSCode though; your browser should look similar.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.